# Excel pivot table group all months by year

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have all my data grouped by year and then sorted by month (in an Excel Pivot Table):

```
2007                                    2008
January    February     March    ...    January    February    March
```

How can I group this as follow:

```
January         February        March
2007    2008    2007    2008    2007    2008
```

I've set the column labels like this but without any succes.

**Columns labels**

- Month
- Year

Then I get this:

```
January    February    March
2007       2007        2007
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't just move the labels, move the fields. You should have you field selection area, and be able to see the list of things you're showing in the columns. Reorder them there.

Comment: Can you explain this in a bit more detail? I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. Should I reorder them in the PivotTable Field List? http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/9453/2601201185523.png

Comment: At the bottom of that image, in orange. Swap them around.

Comment: I've tried that but then I get a result as my last example (in the question).

Comment: It sounds to me like your Month field also contains information about what year it is.

Comment: This was indeed the problem!